# Unable to produce json response issuing get requests with parameters

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, parameters, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to fetch json response from a [webpage](https://www.capterra.com/360-degree-feedback-software/) issuing get http requests with appropriate parameters but I get `403 Forbidden` as response.  When I do the same in python, I get required response accordingly. However, things go wrong when I go for the following approach:

```
function capterraScraper() {
  var Url = 'https://www.capterra.com/directoryPage/rest/v1/category';
  var params = {
      'htmlName': '360-degree-feedback-software',
      'rbr': 'false',
      'countryCode': 'BD'
  };
  var options = {
    'method' : 'GET',
    'params' : params,
    'headers' : {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'
    }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(Url, options);
  console.log(JSON.parse(response));
}
```

> How can I make the script produce json response?

Comment: Could you show your python script?

Comment: Gite [this](https://pastebin.com/SkAqPnUF) a check @TheMaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your script, I thought that `params` might be used as the query parameter. When I tested it, I confirmed that the JSON data could be obtained. But when I tested the URL using Google Apps Script, I also confirmed the error of `403 Forbidden`. Fortunately, when I accessed the URL using Javascript, the JSON data can be obtained. So in this case, as a workaround, I would like to propose a workaround for using the JSON data at the Google Apps Script side.

The flow of workaround is as follows.

- Open a dialog.
- Retrieving the JSON data using Javascript, and returning the data to Google Apps Script side.

By this, you can use the JSON data at Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet, and run `main()` at the script editor. By this, a dialog is opened at Google Spreadsheet and the JSON data is retrieved, and return the data to the Google Apps Script side.

```js
function main(obj) {
  if (!obj) {
    var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(`<script>fetch('https://www.capterra.com/directoryPage/rest/v1/category?' + (new URLSearchParams({htmlName: '360-degree-feedback-software',rbr: 'false',countryCode: 'BD'}))).then(response => response.json()).then(res => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).main(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));</script>`);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "sample");
    return;
  }
  console.log(obj)
  DriveApp.createFile("sample.txt", JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

- When this sample script is run, the retrieved JSON data is saved in a file on the root folder. Of course, you can use the data as `obj`.
- The Javascript in this script is as follows.

  ```
    <script>
    fetch('https://www.capterra.com/directoryPage/rest/v1/category?' + (new URLSearchParams({htmlName: '360-degree-feedback-software',rbr: 'false',countryCode: 'BD'})))
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(res => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).main(res))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
    </script>
  ```

#### Note:

- This workaround uses a dialog on Google Spreadsheet. So, unfortunately, in this case, even when this script is run from the outside and the time-driven trigger, the script cannot be used. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Workspace Documents](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, how can I use `query parameter` in the right way to form a qualified url in order to send `get requests` because `params=params` doesn't seem right in google apps script. One more thing, how can I install axios in apps script. Thanks a trillion.

Comment: @MITHU Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question 1, I thought that my post might be useful. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/70503e0ea6998083fcb05c6d2a857107) About your new question 2, Google Apps Script cannot use Axios. If you want to use it, it is required to use a dialog as my proposed workaround. I apologize for this.

Comment: I really do not wish to use axios here. I just wanted to learn how to install and use any extrernal libraries like axios e.tc. in apps script.

Comment: @MITHU Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, Axios cannot be used with Google Apps Script. I deeply apologize for this again.